# How to edit a JSON Object as a Form in a Browser

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

I have a store which returns a JSON object. I want to display the JSON object as a form with the value which is editable. Also the user can add new key value pairs to the existing object and on submit the New JSON object should be posted to the API.

Are there any existing libraries or tools which allow me to do it. I am looking to code minimally in Javascript.

Comment: JSON is just a text string... letting a user edit that by hand can "break" the string by rendering it invalid. To be safe, you'd have to convert every key/value pair in the object into a separate input field, plus having to manage arbitrary nesting depths... good luck!

Comment: Marc B : That is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/caolan/forms with http://substack.net/posts/24ab8c may just be the tools you are looking for !!